# Angular Material Snackbar not shown correctly

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, snackbar

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qqf5ox)

Hi community
I implemented a global error handler and a global loading component (angular material spinner) to my angular 7 project.
When detecting a HttpErrorResponse the loader should be removed and an angular material snackbar should be shown.

The snackbar should open at the bottom of the page and should close when clicking "x".

But instead it opens at the upper left side.

[image]

When clicking "x" it closes and opens again at the expected position. But then it doesn't react to clicks anymore. It disappears after clicking "x" and then clicking a different position of the window.

This behaviour is also shown when removing the loading spinner.

Does anybody has an idea how to solve this issue?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The issue is that the snackbar is being ran outside of angular's zone.

A quick fix can be placed in your `SnackbarService` or where the `error` method is being called.

[Stackblitz:src/app/services/snackbar.service.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pt2hth?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fsnackbar.service.ts)

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarRef, SimpleSnackBar, MatSnackBarConfig } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SnackbarService {

  constructor(
    public snackbar: MatSnackBar,
    private zone: NgZone,
  ) { }

  error(message: string) {
    const config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
    config.panelClass = ['background-red'];
    config.verticalPosition = 'bottom';
    config.horizontalPosition = 'center';
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.snackbar.open(message, 'x', config);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Waaaaaaaaaah that's it! Thank you thank you thank you! You definitely made my day, woohoo!

Comment: Thanks for this - helped me out

Answer (score 1):

I had the almost the same error , but my snacbar show in outside my parent component.
In devtools I had warning thad said me - my material version not coincide with angular cdk version - than i update my material to latest and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

If in your devtools you get this warning : "**Could not find Angular Material core theme..**" then the solution is simply to import a material theme css, in my case i added this line to my style.scss:

```
@import 'assets/css/material/indigo-pink.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

Because mat-snack-bar-container is outside screen.

This will help

```
::ng-deep .mat-snack-bar-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 40px; /* Adjust this value to set the vertical position */
  left: 50%; /* Adjust this value to set the horizontal position */
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: BTW, you can alternatively achieve the same behavior by adding the style to the global style.css file , Just remove the `::ng-deep` and  leave the rest.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if any of these will fix your problem, but I had the same issues...now I no longer do. (lol)

Try changing any private constructor instances to public. Also pass in the options param with properties of 'horizontalPosition' to 'center' and 'verticalPosition' to 'bottom'.

I'm on mobile but if you want to toss up a stackblitz I can take a closer look. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kevin thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, doing the changes you suggested does not solve the issue, see stackblitz example that is linked in my first post.